# Finding "gaps" in data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have data about pulications, which contain issn, year, volume and issue. So for example

```
1234-x000, 2013, 1, 2
1234-x000, 2013, 1, 1
1234-x000, 2012, 6, 2
1234-x000, 2012, 6, 1
1234-x000, 2012, 5, 2
....
4321-yyyy, 2013, 2, 1
4321-yyyy, 2013, 1, 1
4321-yyyy, 2012, 12, 1
4321-yyyy, 2012, 11, 1
....
```

I want to identify missing data. One problem is, that the volume/issue structure is not always the same. So for one issn there might be 12 issues per volume or only 6 or ... But the number per year an issn can be assumed to be fixed.

My pandas knowledge is still very basic. I have the feeling, that I should be able to identify the missing values with a few lines of clever pandas code, but I don't get it. Any hint how to solve that?

Comment: Can give some examples for your missing data case?

Comment: For a given year, there might be volumes 1,2,3,4,6,7,...12. So volume 5 would be missing.

Comment: What if miss the last volume or last issue for a volume?

Comment: That would also be a "missing value" or a gap. "Gap" might not be good term if you just look at the year or volume, but if you take the whole data into account it's ok again. ;-)

Comment: How would you know that you have missing data, if the item that should have 12 volumes only has the first 6?

Comment: There are always multiple years, so it's not know if a certain issn has always 4 or 6 or ... volumes/issues. But it should be the same for each year. If the last volume or issue is 10 for all years, that's fine and the data can be considered being complete. If one year has a volume 11 and/or 12, but not the others, there's something missing.

Comment: how many possibilities are there? 6,12...something else?

Comment: It's better that you give a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full solution, for example it assumes, that the last volume is always present. But as you asked for a pointer, this should get you going:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
        issn  year  vol  issue
0  1234-x000  2013    1      2
1  1234-x000  2013    1      1
2  1234-x000  2012    6      2
3  1234-x000  2012    6      1
4  1234-x000  2012    5      2
5  4321-yyyy  2013    2      1
6  4321-yyyy  2013    1      1
7  4321-yyyy  2012   12      1
8  4321-yyyy  2012   11      1

In [29]: vols = df.groupby('issn').vol.max()

In [30]: vols
Out[30]: 
issn
1234-x000     6
4321-yyyy    12
Name: vol

In [31]: for k, g in df.groupby(['issn','year']):
    ...:     print k
    ...:     print 'missing: ', np.setdiff1d(np.arange(1, vols[k[0]]+1),
    ...:                                                g.issue.values)
```

output:

```
('1234-x000', 2012)
missing:  [ 3.  4.  5.  6.]
('1234-x000', 2013)
missing:  [ 3.  4.  5.  6.]
('4321-yyyy', 2012)
missing:  [  2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.]
('4321-yyyy', 2013)
missing:  [  2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. I would add two columns 'idx' and 'max'

```
In [452]: df['idx'] = df.groupby(['issn']).apply(lambda sdf: (sdf.volume - 1) * sdf.issue.max() + sdf.issue)

In [453]: df
Out[453]:
        issn  year  volume  issue  idx
0  1234-x000  2013       1      2    2
1  1234-x000  2013       1      1    1
2  1234-x000  2012       6      2   12
3  1234-x000  2012       6      1   11
4  1234-x000  2012       5      2   10
5  4321-yyyy  2013       2      1    2
6  4321-yyyy  2013       1      1    1
7  4321-yyyy  2012      12      1   12
8  4321-yyyy  2012      11      1   11

In [454]: df['max'] = df.groupby(['issn']).idx.transform(lambda s: s.max())

In [455]: df
Out[455]:
        issn  year  volume  issue  idx  max
0  1234-x000  2013       1      2    2   12
1  1234-x000  2013       1      1    1   12
2  1234-x000  2012       6      2   12   12
3  1234-x000  2012       6      1   11   12
4  1234-x000  2012       5      2   10   12
5  4321-yyyy  2013       2      1    2   12
6  4321-yyyy  2013       1      1    1   12
7  4321-yyyy  2012      12      1   12   12
8  4321-yyyy  2012      11      1   11   12
```

The previous answer provides the rest

```
In [462]: df.groupby(['issn', 'year']).apply(lambda sdf: np.setdiff1d(range(1, sdf['max'].irow(0)), sdf.idx).tolist())
Out[462]:
issn       year
1234-x000  2012        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
           2013      [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
4321-yyyy  2012    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
           2013      [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```